# Open Teamviewer From Your Website

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, teamviewer

Does someone know if it's possible to open a teamviewer session from your website?
I got some Teamviewer ID's in a table. It wil be nice that i could open teamviewer on my laptop from my website. Clicking on the Teamviewer ID in the table offcourse..

Suggestions?

Comment: The only way would be javascript and if that was possible all our PC's would be the slave of whichever hacker got to us first

Comment: I think you get me wrong. I work in a company were we are responsible for over 200 computers. We all got the Teamviewer ID's and there all set to unattended acces. Where we know password from. I made a simple control pannel to structure al the teamviewer ID to the hostname's.. I got a table with al laptop's with their teamviewer ID's. I want when i click on a Teamviewer ID, it opens my teamviewer, to connect with the ID. Like you do in TeamViewer Management Console.. Regards,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092319/how-to-start-teamviewer-session-on-the-basis-of-teamviewerid-in-asp-net/22092823#22092823

Comment: you can access teamviewer from the browser, by doing:   `window.location = teamviewer8://remotecontrol?connectcc=######`

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is not a duplicate. Giels Evens is not asking to open any software, just Teamviewer. And if TeamViewer is installed on the computer, you can launch the local client by using proper URL in the browser. I would like to post and answer, so please reevaluate your `Duplicate` tag.

Comment: @m Ok, opened again.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier Do you have an answer for this question then?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, i've just posted it

Answer (score 4):

If TeamViewer is installed (and because TeamViewer register a *Custom URI Scheme* in Windows during the installation), you can simply create a link to make your browser launch the client. Two methods:

**Direct link**

It use directly the custom URI scheme:

```
teamviewer8://remotecontrol?connectcc=[TargetComputerId]
```

**Link to the TeamViewer website**

It will check if TeamViewer is installed and download the installer if not.
If TeamViewer is installed, it will lauch the TeamViewer client.

```
https://start.teamviewer.com/device/[TargetComputerId]/authorization/password/mode/control
```

**Notes**

- Both of the links can be used in a `<a href="" />` tag, or the `window.location=` JS command.
- The browser will ask you to confirm the external application opening.

Comment: Is there any way to use `teamviewer8://remotecontrol?connectcc=[TargetComputerId]` with IP address, I'm in VPN connection and there is no internet

Comment: I found it `tvcontrol1://control?device=[IP or computerId]`

Comment: BTW, if you just want to start the teamviewer client in the machine which is running the browser you can try this. 
*teamviewer8://remotecontrol?connectcc=NNN (any number for NNN)*
I tried and seems to just open the TeamViewer client